# R: refer to var in different list element on a looped condition

Tags: r, list, if-statement, conditional-statements, purrr

I've got a dataset with a number of vars (`t01`-`t05` in a dummy example but many more in the real dataset). I calculate `pred` variable as a proportion of `target == 1/n()` per all group-level combinations (5th element in the `ns_by_group_list`). However, if the total number of people in that combination (`s` var) less than 6, I need to use the `pred` value from the equivalent `t01`-`t04` combination (4th element of `ns_by_group_list`). If this one is less than 6, then from `t01`-`t03` combinations (3rd element of `ns_by_group_list`), etc. The final output should look like `ns_by_group_list[[5]]` but with pred values coming from different `ns_by_group_list list` elements.

I was thinking of renaming `pred` and `s` vars in different list elements to `pred1`, `pred2`, .. `pred5` and then pulling it all together to one data.frame, then create a long `case_when` statement... But surely there's a better/more elegant way to do it?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

## functions ####
create_t_labels <- function(n) {
  paste0('t', str_pad(1:n, 2, 'left', '0'))
}
ns_by_group <- function(group_vars) {
  input %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = vars(group_vars)) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%  # total number of people in each group
    ungroup() %>% 
    spread(key = target, value = n) %>%
    mutate(`0` = replace_na(`0`, 0),
           n = replace_na(`1`, 0),
           s = n + `0`,
           pred = round(n/s, 3)
    ) %>%
    select(-c(`1`, `0`)) 
}
### input data #### 
set.seed(1)
input <- tibble(
  target = sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE),
  t01 = sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE),
  t02 = rep(1:2, each = 25),
  t03 =   rep(1:5, each = 10),
  t04 = rep(1, 50),
  t05 = rep(1:2, each = 25)
)
## calculations ####
group_combo_list <- map(1:5, create_t_labels)
group_combo_list <- map(group_combo_list, function(x) c(x, 'target'))
ns_by_group_list <- map(group_combo_list, ns_by_group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively joining and replacing:

```
reduce(
  ns_by_group_list,
  ~ {
    left_join(.y, .x, by = grep("^t\\d+$", names(.x), value = TRUE),
              suffix = c("", ".replacement")) %>% 
      mutate(pred = if_else(s < 6, pred.replacement, pred),
             s = if_else(s < 6, s.replacement, s)) %>% 
      select(-ends_with(".replacement"))
  },
  .dir = "backward"
)

# # A tibble: 16 x 8
#      t01   t02   t03   t04   t05     n     s  pred
#    <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1     1     1     1     1     1    16 0.562
#  2     1     1     2     1     1     1    16 0.562
#  3     1     2     3     1     2     2    12 0.583
#  4     1     2     4     1     2     4     6 0.667
#  5     1     2     5     1     2     1    12 0.583
#  6     2     1     1     1     1     3    13 0.385
#  7     2     1     2     1     1     2     6 0.333
#  8     2     1     3     1     1     0    13 0.385
#  9     2     2     4     1     2     1     6 0.5  
# 10     2     2     5     1     2     2     6 0.5  
# 11     3     1     1     1     1     0     8 0.125
# 12     3     1     2     1     1     1     8 0.125
# 13     3     1     3     1     1     0     8 0.125
# 14     3     2     3     1     2     0     7 0.714
# 15     3     2     4     1     2     1     7 0.714
# 16     3     2     5     1     2     4     7 0.714
```

Comment: this is genius, thank you! Didn't know about `reduce()` until now, very handy